# How can I make sure an instance is not deallocated?

Tags: ios, uitableview, asynchronous, synchronization, exc-bad-access

In my app, I am loading images for UITableViewCells asynchronously like this:

```
-(void) loadImage:(NSString *)urlString cell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
    UIImageView *iv = cell.imageView;

    UIImage *image = [imageCache objectForKey:urlString];
    if(!image) {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
        if(image) {
            [imageCache setObject:image forKey:urlString];
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        iv.image = image;
        [cell addSubview:iv];
    });
}
```

When the tableview is refreshed before all of the images have finished loading, an exception is thrown on `iv.image = image;` because iv has been deallocated.  What is the best way to make sure I never try to set an image for a deallocated cell?  Is there some way to kill any lingering asynchronous loads when the tableview is reloaded?

Comment: [ARC](http://maniacdev.com/ios-5-sdk-tutorial-and-guide/arc-automatic-reference-counting/) or not?

Comment: The block is keeping a reference, so it should not be deallocated. Also, call to a deallocated object (nil) does not give exc-bad-access

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this other way around. Try to get an image from cache when you are constructing the cell. If the image is not found trigger on asynchronous download and notify cell or controller (from main thread) that image was downloaded. You can use KVO to connect cells with images cache.

Comment: That is a great idea.  I haven't used KVO before (new to iOS), but it looks extremely useful here.